# How to merge 2 excels with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two excel files I would like to merge:

```
file1        file2
   a   b        a     b
1  AA  aa    1  AA   aaaa
2  BB  bb    2  BB   bbbb
3  CC  cc    3  CC   cccc
4  DD  dd
5  EE  ee
```

with:

```
all_data_st = pd.merge( file1, file2, on="Unique")
```

I was able to merge and receive:

```
 file3
   a     b   c
1  AA   aa   aaaa
2  BB   bb   bbbb
3  CC   cc   cccc
```

but, I would like to receive:

```
 file4
   a     b   c
1  AA   aa   aaaa
2  BB   bb   bbbb
3  CC   cc   cccc
4  DD   dd
5  EE   ee
```

Please advise the formula. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your dataframes as,

```
file1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"], "b": ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]})
file2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["AA", "BB", "CC"], "b": ["aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"]})
```

Use:

```
all_data_st = (
    pd.merge(file1, file2, on="a", how="left")
    .fillna('').rename(columns={"b_x": "b", "b_y": "c"}))

print(all_data_st)
```

This results:

```
    a   b     c
0  AA  aa  aaaa
1  BB  bb  bbbb
2  CC  cc  cccc
3  DD  dd      
4  EE  ee
```

Comment: Still have some issues, but maybe it's the final format problem. Is it possible to sort result columns to receive c,a,b

Comment: just reorder the columns using `df = df[['c', 'a', 'b']]`.